# How do Flutter transforms an AOT Snapshot into a SharedObject (.so)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am playing with different snapshots for Flutter and is known that it uses the AOT snapshot for Release builds.

When you do a `dart2aot main.dart main.aot` command on CLI you get the aot snapshot file that is can only be executed by a Dart runtime.

But looking inside the Android APK, you only find a single **shared object** file called `flutter.so`.

I am probably wrong, but as I know a shared object file (.so) is a compiled code generated by C++ or C languages.

So my question is:

**How Flutter does this kind of compilation? How it transform the `.aot` dart file into a shared object file that needs no dart runtime to be executed?**